# How do I allocate a button for each seat on a seating map?

Tags: javascript

Here's the thing :

The page already has a png of the seating map of theatres, each seat layout in black lines.

what I want to do: allocate a square button to each seat, so that when u press the button it will depict a picture of the view from that particular seat.

so following questions :

what can I do to allocate a button to each seat? Do I give the buttons a corresponding grid value?

Heres a reference for u to visualise...
https://www.lgart.com/uipage/guide/seat.aspx

Its in Korean but u'll get the hang of it once u see it.

Also disclaimer: I'm a newbie at Javascript so I may be struggling with the easiest problems...

Comment: oops its javascript, sorry bout that

Comment: Aren't you already achieving this? Clicking on the red spheres will update the image to the right (albeit very slowly).

Comment: Hi,  your gird nodes should have location/coordinate indices for lines and columns like (x,y) etc. use them also to map your pictures in the background. When clicked, button could show the picture in a small rectangle area. Alternatively, instead of buttons, you can use just seat icons and add hover functionality to them. when you hover mouse pointer over the icon, picture could be shown.

Comment: I would suggest using SVG instead of image maps. SVGs can be treated as individual dom elements, meaning you can use javascript and css to manipulate them individually. Tools like sketch/figma have an [export option](https://www.sketch.com/docs/exporting/#how-to-export-css-and-svg-code) that lets you copy paste SVG code into your file.

Comment: thanks antiq n mroritzsalla, i'll try that!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to overlay these buttons over a PNG image, you'll probably end up needing to use some sort of [image map](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp). However, my suggestion in this case, which is a more modern way of accomplishing a task like this would be to put together an SVG version of the seating chart, where each seat shape/path in the SVG would have its own unique `id`. That way, you can set up an event listener in your JavaScript for any seat click and trigger any actions you'd like.

Here's a similar mini-project I built a while back to explore this concept, using the United States map. In my example below, I actually used checkbox inputs to track the checked status of any given state, but I would suggest for your case to just set up the event listener and add custom classes to your seat shapes/paths if you need any custom styling when the seat is selected.

https://cdpn.io/e/MWWLVqw

****Make sure to open this snippet as a "Full Page" to see the map**

```css
html, body { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; } iframe { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<p class="codepen" data-height="265" data-theme-id="dark" data-default-tab="html,result" data-user="brandonmcconnell" data-slug-hash="MWWLVqw" data-editable="true" style="height: 265px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;" data-pen-title="Interactive / Selectable Map">
  <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/brandonmcconnell/pen/MWWLVqw">
  Interactive / Selectable Map</a> by Brandon McConnell (<a href="https://codepen.io/brandonmcconnell">@brandonmcconnell</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
</p>
<script async src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```